# ¿Cómo puedo abrir y modificar un archivo .So?

Tags: android, archivo

Hace poco estuve revisando un juego para Android mediante el apk, pero me encontré con librerías compartidas (lib.so), estuve leyendo sobre estos tipos de archivos, pero sin éxito alguno probé distintas aplicaciones para poder modificar estos archivos, pero ni siquiera me deja abrir el archivo.

¿Cómo puedo abrir y editar este tipo de archivos?
No importa si es en el PC o en el celular

Answer (score 2):

Los archivos con extensión `.so` son archivos compilados, por esta razón no pueden modificados.

Si tienes el código fuente para crear los módulos podrías generar un nuevo `.so` de otra forma sería un poco difícil aunque no imposible usando ingeniería inversa.